# Can I say that the 'to-infinitive which is part of predicative is an object?

Tags: infinitives, predicate-nominative

The **infinitive as object** as in *"He asked me to come in."* & the **to-infinitive as part of predicative** as in '*The house of Jane was not easy to find'* both act as noun. Both of these 'to come & to find' are these object?

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *He asked me* [*to come in*].
>
> [2] *Jane's house was not easy* [*to find*].

No, the bracketed infinitival clauses are not objects.

[1] is a catenative construction where the infinitival clause *to come in* is catenative complement of *asked*. *Me* is the direct object of *asked* and the understood subject of *to come in*.

In [2] the infinitival clause *to find* is complement of the adjective *easy* -- they form the adjective phrase *easy to find*.